# Images not updating on my page

Tags: image, png

I have a page running with Apache 2.2, MySQL 5 and PHP 5.3. Everytime I edit an image on my page it doesn't update. I tested it on Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but it still doesn't work. I can't really show code because it's very large files and I don't know wich code to show? The images is PNG images.

How can I let the images always update automatically?